# URP lights are not working in unity, they first worked

Tags: unity-game-engine, pipeline, renderer, urp

My project uses the URP lights that were well configured, but a while ago they stopped working, they even disappeared in the menu, the lights that are in the scene do not work and there is the following error: "error 2d renderer data must be assigned to your urp asset or camera". I am not able to fix this error.

[No URP lights, and the lights error is global or normal that already had in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zIGq.png)

[It has URP lights, but it doesn't let you add it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS5bJ.png)

[URP configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3z0g.png)

[URP configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vOUt.png)

I have already reinstalled the URP and configured it again and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you change something recently?  Compare changes in source control.  Did you upgrade Unity?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded to unity, had version 2021.3.14f1 and upgraded to version 2021.3.15f1. And now I'm upgrading to 2021.3.16f1, because sometimes it can be bug!?

I spent a long time doing the keyboard settings menu scene in version 2021.3.15f1, I was so distracted doing it that I hadn't noticed the lights, when suddenly when doing the levels I realized that they weren't working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, so please check them one by one.

Is this a Render Pipeline Asset for 2D?

[image]

[image]

Have you set it to Quality setting?

[image]

Did you set it to Graphics setting?

[image]

Is the Camera's Renderer specified as Default Renderer or 2d's Renderer Pipeline?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have exactly that. I repeated this several times. I even created a new URP template project and the problem persists.

Comment: Practically the 2d lights which should be in the menu are gone, even in the header there are the lights but you can't click.

Comment: And the lights that are in the scene have this error. "2d renderer data must be assigned to your urp asset or camera"

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of your Main Camera?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, it was my mistake and stupid I hadn't noticed it all these days and that an easy error to solve in quality had universalURP instead of URP2D.